# C/C++ type that can be translated into a `i256` variable in LLVM IR

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I noticed that in LLVM IR there are some quite long types, such as `i256`, `i256*`. However, even if I compile `unsigned long long` variable into LLVM IR, its corresponding type is `i64`.

So my question is that what kinda of `C/C++` variable can be compiled into a `i256` variable in LLVM IR? Thanks.

Comment: What instructions are they used with, it may indicate a chip extended register? SIMD (used in AVX/AVX2) have been extended from 128 to 256 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bitfield structures to get an the internal `i256` data type. For example :

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long long a : 64 ;
    unsigned long long b : 64 ;
    unsigned long long c : 64 ;
    unsigned long long d : 64 ;
} S;

S a = {1,1};

S f() {
    return a;
}
```

compiled with options : `clang -emit-llvm -g0 -O0`

The generated IR is as follows:

```
%struct.S = type { i256 }
```

Link : https://godbolt.org/z/QufAIn